# PyCharm подскази

Tags: pycharm

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что появляются вот такие подсказки. Выдает даже когда ввожу банально название функции новой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такие подсказки норм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить эту ситуацию? Везде поискал, не нашёл

Comment: Видимо вы пишите методы в классе-потомке, и PyCharm предлагает методы, которые можно переопределить.

Comment: Ой, да. Спасибо большое, тупанул)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писал методы в классе-потомке, из-за этого PyCharm предлагал методы которые можно предопределить.